# три виджета Text используют одну переменную

Tags: flutter, dart

Три виджета Text используют одну переменную str. При нажатии на кнопку рандомным способом выбирается один из виджетов Text и ему присваивается значение, а у других виджетов Text значение остается. **Вопрос**. Как идентифицировать эти виджеты Text? Возможно ли такое? Например, у JavaScript есть атрибут **id**.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   home: MyHomePage()
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 String str = 'Hello World!';
 bool b = false;

 void f1() {
  setState(() {
   int a = math.Random().nextInt(3);
   switch(a) {
    case 0: //#0 должно изменить текст в виджете Text #0
     str = '$a';
     break;
    case 1: //#1 должно изменить текст в виджете Text #1
     str = '$a';
     break;
    case 2: //#2 должно изменить текст в виджете Text #2
     str = '$a';
     break;
   }
  });
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
       Text( //#0 как сделать здесь идентификатор?
        str,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.red,
         fontSize: 32.0
        ),
       ),
       Text( //#1 как сделать здесь идентификатор?
        str,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.green,
         fontSize: 32.0
        ),
       ),
       Text( //#2 как сделать здесь идентификатор?
        str,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.blue,
         fontSize: 32.0
        ),
       ),
       Expanded(
        child: FittedBox(
         fit: BoxFit.contain,
         child: CupertinoButton(
          onPressed: f1,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Text(
           'Ok',
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ),

      ],
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все же прочитайте что из себя представляет [декларативное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и узнайте [разницу между императивном программированием](https://tproger.ru/translations/imperative-declarative-programming-concepts/).

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String str = 'Hello World!';
  int a;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            (a == 0) ? a.toString() : str,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
          Text(
            (a == 1) ? a.toString() : str,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
          Text(
            (a == 2) ? a.toString() : str,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: CupertinoButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => a = math.Random().nextInt(3)),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Text(
                  'Ok',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Anton пожалуйста! Если будут вопросы спрашивайте!

Comment: onPressed: () => setState(() => a = math.Random().nextInt(3)), почему Вы setState выполняете непосредственно в обработчике, а не где нибудь в методе? Или все равно где?

Comment: @Anton если делать по хорошему, то логику приложения вообще надо выносить за UI. А так, когда код не большой можно и внутри обработчика написать (+ функциональный стиль все упрощает), но если было-бы N строк  то выносят в отдельный метод. В общем разницы нет)